# how to insert text field in the place of string in pdf using java

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am currently working on inserting a Digital Signature (DS) to pdf documents using IText API Java. I am  able to attach DS in pdf documents but my requirement is I want to insert DS at the location of placeholder(string). I tried many ways but nothing is working. Does anybody know how to implement the same...?
I tried another way of doing the same by adding a text field to pdf and attaching a DS inside text field using text field name. But again the problem is I am not able to add a Text field at the place of String. How to add a text field in pdf at a required location...?(i.e I want to replace a string with text field) is this possible...?.Does anybody know how new Rectangle() can be created in java at the location of placeholder (String or text).

Comment: add a text field in a pdf? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Lets say i have a pdf and at first page of pdf theres a text called ds. I want to replace a text with text field so that i can insert DS inside text field.

Comment: First of all PDF is not a writing thing, it is a file format for documents just like `.doc` etc

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I know but is it possible to do so...?

Comment: short answer, no

Comment: Your second approach, *"I tried another way of doing the same by adding a text field to pdf and attaching a DS inside text field using text field name"*, is better, but instead of *adding a text field* you can simply add an empty (i.e. unsigned) signature field which you can easily sign using iText.

Comment: @mkl I dont want do the things manually. I have to generate the pdf along with digital signature in a single click.

Comment: How do you create that pdf? I ask because adding an empty signature field need not be a manual action.

Comment: If you have found a solution and are no longer interested in an answer, please either answer your question yourself sketching your solution or delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class TextRenderInfoObject with fields as

```
private String text;
private TextRenderInfo line;
```

add all constructors, getters and setters.

To get the Co-Ordinates of Text (Placeholder)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());  
List<TextRenderInfoObject> textRenderInfos = new ArrayList<>();  
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);  
parser.processContent(pageNumber, new TextMarginFinder()
{
    @Override  
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {  
        if("dstext".contains(renderInfo.getText()))
        {  
            textRenderInfos.add(new TextRenderInfoObject(  
            renderInfo.getText(), renderInfo));
        }
    }
}

Rectangle2D.Float line;  
for (TextRenderInfoObject textRenderInfo : textRenderInfos)  
{
    if (textRenderInfo.getText().equals("dstext"))  
        line = textRenderInfo.getLine().getBaseline().getBoundingRectange());
}
```

Creating form field in pdf

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, byteArrayOutputStream);  
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(stamper.getWriter()); 
field.setFieldName("Digital Signature");
field.setWidget(new Rectangle(line.x, line.y, line.x + line.width, line.y - line.height), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE);
field.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);  
field.setColor(BaseColor.WHITE);  
field.setMKBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);  
stamper.addAnnotation(field, pageNumber);  
stamper.close();
```

Comment: It's not only the formatting, a part of at least one line is missing.

Comment: Find the Co-ordinates of place holder where you want to insert form field.Store it in the form of Rectangle2D.Float. It can be done using TextRenderInfoObject.I am not able to copy paste the code here. How to format the java code in this editor.

Comment: *"How to format the java code in this editor."* - Indent by at least 4 spaces or one tab. I did that for you but your initial piece of code is missing something.

Comment: @mkl Finally formatted text. Try that it will work for sure

Comment: *" it will work for sure"* - Well, not always because a text chunk reported via a `renderText` call back can be longer than the place holder "dstext" (making the check in `renderText` fail), or shorter (making the check in your `for` loop fail), or might even merely overlap a part of it (making both checks mentioned above fail). For simple enough PDFs it can work, though.

Comment: Well it worked for me for the text of 28 digit (placeholder) @mkl

Comment: @mkl Can u please check this question. Any Way do that URL :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440583/linking-pdfs-of-portable-collection-using-itext?noredirect=1#comment93754460_53440583.