# Linking pdfs of Portable Collection using Itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I have portable collection in that total of two pdf document is there. My requirement is that if I open one pdf document and click the link or any text, it should redirect to another pdf of that portable Collection.

For example: Consider there are two pdfs inside a portable collection namely Programming.pdf and Java.pdf. If I click any particular text or variable inside Programming.pdf, it should redirect to Java.pdf. Is it possible...?.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @mkl Any suggestions.

Comment: That would require *Embedded Go-To actions*; I have not played around with them yet. Probably I find some time to do so this week.

Comment: @mkl please update if you get any solution.

Comment: @mkl please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451570/how-to-get-number-of-pages-of-portable-collection-pdf-using-itext-or-any-functio

Comment: @Nagaraj Does my answer solve your issue here? If not, which are the open problems?

Comment: I tried to implement it. I Could not get the proper result. I have to implement it later once i get time. @mkl

Answer (score 0):

To navigate between documents in a portable collection, you have to employ *Embedded Go-To actions*. They in particular contain a **T**arget dictionary which actually can be the start of a chain of target dictionaries to navigate between collection members with arbitrary embedding depths. To navigate between sibling documents, you need one target dictionary going up to the parent document containing another target dictionary going down again from that parent to the desired sibling. For details cf. ISO 32000-2 section 12.6.4.4 "Embedded Go-To actions".

In iText 5.x you build such embedded goto actions like this:

```java
PdfTargetDictionary sibbling = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);
sibbling.setEmbeddedFileName(linkId);
PdfTargetDictionary parent = new PdfTargetDictionary(sibbling);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Go to " + linkId + ".");
PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, -1, -1, 0);
dest.addFirst(new PdfNumber(0));
PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoEmbedded(null, parent, dest, false);
chunk.setAction(action);
document.add(chunk);
```

*(from [EmbeddedLinks](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/EmbeddedLinks.java#L99) helper `createPage`)*

For example the following test creates a portfolio with four documents A, B, C, and D which all contain links to each other:

```java
public void testLinkToSibblingInPortfolio() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Files.write(new File("portfolio-with-embedded-gotos.pdf").toPath(), createPdf(new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"}));
}

public byte[] createPdf(String[] allIds) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("This document contains a collection of PDFs."));

    PdfCollection collection = new PdfCollection(PdfCollection.HIDDEN);
    PdfCollectionSchema schema = getCollectionSchema(); 
    collection.setSchema(schema);
    PdfCollectionSort sort = new PdfCollectionSort("TITLE");
    collection.setSort(sort);
    collection.setInitialDocument("A");
    writer.setCollection(collection);

    PdfFileSpecification fs;
    PdfCollectionItem item;
    for (String id : allIds) {
        fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, null,
            String.format("%s.pdf", id),
            createPage(id, allIds));
        fs.addDescription(id, false);

        item = new PdfCollectionItem(schema);
        item.addItem("TITLE", id);
        fs.addCollectionItem(item);
        writer.addFileAttachment(fs);
    }

    document.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public byte[] createPage(String id, String[] allIds) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(id,
        FontFactory.getFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED, 48));
    document.add(p);

    for (String linkId : allIds) {
        if (!id.equals(linkId)) {
            PdfTargetDictionary sibbling = new PdfTargetDictionary(true);
            sibbling.setEmbeddedFileName(linkId);
            PdfTargetDictionary parent = new PdfTargetDictionary(sibbling);
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Go to " + linkId + ".");
            PdfDestination dest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, -1, -1, 0);
            dest.addFirst(new PdfNumber(0));
            PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoEmbedded(null, parent, dest, false);
            chunk.setAction(action);
            document.add(chunk);
        }
    }

    document.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

private static PdfCollectionSchema getCollectionSchema() {
    PdfCollectionSchema schema = new PdfCollectionSchema();

    PdfCollectionField size = new PdfCollectionField("File size", PdfCollectionField.SIZE);
    size.setOrder(2);
    schema.addField("SIZE", size);

    PdfCollectionField filename = new PdfCollectionField("File name", PdfCollectionField.FILENAME);
    filename.setVisible(false);
    schema.addField("FILE", filename);

    PdfCollectionField title = new PdfCollectionField("Title", PdfCollectionField.TEXT);
    title.setOrder(0);
    schema.addField("TITLE", title);

    return schema;
}
```

*([EmbeddedLinks](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/EmbeddedLinks.java#L56) test `testLinkToSibblingInPortfolio` and helpers `createPdf`, `createPage`, and `getCollectionSchema`)*

This actually borrows a lot from the iText examples [KubrickBox](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#611-kubrickbox.java), [KubrickCollection](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#612-kubrickcollection.java), and [KubrickMovies](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#615-kubrickmovies.java).

---

<sub>Tested with the current iText 5 development version 5.5.14-SNAPSHOT.</sub>